# Filtering .csv file by a range of values in a specific column WITHOUT using awk or sed

Tags: c, regex, bash, csv, unix

I have a csv file where the data is stored like this, with a space as the delimiting character:

```
181.221.132.87 2020-03-01T06:22:47.775Z "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

I have to print all the lines where the 5th column (in this case the column with the value "1") has a value greater than 5. The catch is that I am limited in the unix commands I can use and have been told that I specifically cannot use awk or sed. Anything that cannot be accomplished with the list of commands provided to us must be implemented with custom C programs however, the emphasis is to use custom programs as little as possible.

Unix commands I can use are as follows:
cat curl cut echo exec egrep find grep head
ls paste printf sort tail tr uniq wc

Sorry if a similar question has been asked before but I cannot find a starting point that doesn't include awk or sed

EDIT:

```
{ egrep " "[5-9]{1}" " file.csv; egrep " "[0-9]{2}" "file.csv; }
```

The above command seems to give the correct output, however I feel there is a better solution.

Comment: Does the field with `"` will always be the same ?

Comment: @Ôrel No the data in this field can change, however eveything inside quotes should be counted as one filed.

Comment: does the position will be the same ?
can `\"` be inside the field ?

Comment: It appears you mean that a space is the delimiting character, except for spaces in strings that are surrounded by double quotes. If so, you should edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with!

```sh
egrep --color '^(("[^"]*"|[^"]\S*)\s+){4}([1-9][0-9]|[6-9])' file.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `^` is the start of the line
- `("[^"]*"|[^"]\S*)\s+)` is one cell, it's composed of 2 possibilities:

  - `"[^"]*"` This is a string cell, surrounded by quotes, and which cannot contain any quotes in its body
  - `[^"]\S*)\s+` This is a normal cell, which can contain anything except white spaces (`\s` is a white space, `\S` is a non white space)
- `{4}` We repeat that 4 times, for the first 4 cells
- `([1-9][0-9]|[6-9])` This is your number, composed of 2 possibilities again:

  - `[1-9][0-9]` It's more than 10
  - `[6-9]` It's more than 5

As for the color flag, it... adds color to the command, it makes it easier when you're creating a regex on the go, to have a visual representation of what is matched:
[image: Demo]

On some system the `--color` is there by default, so you might not see the difference

Comment: Awesome thanks! Would you mind explaining what the color flag does?

Comment: I explained it in my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry i missed that bit, thanks you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Without grep

```
cat log| while read line
do
  v=`echo $line | cut -d'"' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,3 | tr -s ' '|cut -f4 -d' ' `
  if [ "$v" -gt 5 ]
  then
    echo $line
  fi                               
done
```

read the file line by line with `while read line`

split " with `cut` odd are fields without " even values inside the "

```
cut -d'"' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,3
```

give
    181.221.132.87 2020-03-01T06:22:47.775Z   200 1

remove double spaces with tr

```
cut -d'"' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,3 | tr -s ' '
```

gives

```
181.221.132.87 2020-03-01T06:22:47.775Z 200 1
```

get the field at pos 4 with cut

```
cut -d'"' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,3 | tr -s ' '|cut -f4 -d' '
```

gives

```
1
```

then check against 5 in pure bash `[ "$v" -gt 5 ]`